# Match only ASCII letters in regular expression, ignoring umlauts

Tags: bash, regular-expression, locale, unicode, special-characters

I use a regex in my bash script like

```
REGEX="^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+$"
```

I want to filter out all non standard words, especially words containing german special characters `äöüÄÖÜß`

but according to [this manual](http://de.wiki-aventurica.de/wiki/Hilfe:Regular_Expressions) if you set your LOCALE to german, the regex `a-z` also contians `ö`

How do I solve this?

I already tried to set my locales at the start of the script to english with:

```
#!/bin/bash
LANG=en_US.utf8
LANGUAGE=en_US.utf8
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
export LANG
export LANGUAGE
export LC_ALL
```

but no effect.

I don't want to do this workaround and replace the special characters beforehand:

```
tr _ -|tr . -|tr " " -|tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'|sed 's/ä/ae/;s/ö/oe/;s/ü/ue/;s/ß/ss/g')
```

I would rather learn the correct way.

Comment: See also [Converting a UTF-8 file to ASCII (best-effort)](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171832)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
REGEXP='^[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0-9-]+$'
```

To select which characters you want. What's matched by `[a-z]` is only guaranteed to be `[abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz]` in the C/POSIX locale.

(I assume you don't  want the backslash to be included, but that `\` was a misguided attempt at escaping the `-`).

Another option is to fix the locale to C before using the tool that evaluates that `^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$` extended regexp (or `^[[:alnum:]-]+$`), like:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -Ee "$REGEXP"
```

That's valid in this case, but not in cases like `REGEXP='[A-Z]'` in case the data to match the regexp against is in a charset like BIG5-HKSCS or GB18030 (and in locales that use that same character) where many characters have encodings that contain the same encoding as those of `A-Z`.

Example where `[A-Z]` matches on `Á` (U+00C1, encoded as 0x88 0x57 in BIG5-HKSCS (where 0x57 is also `W`)):

```
$ LC_ALL=zh_HK.big5hkscs REGEXP='[A-Z]' bash -c 'printf "\uc1\n" |
    LC_ALL=C grep -qe "$REGEXP" && echo match'
match
```

Comment: and thx for the backslach tip, I thought the backslash works correct in my script although it might be obsolete, but you were correct

Comment: No, fixing the locale as C will not work correctly in many cases (except utf-8). Grep, under a C locale matches bytes, not characters. Try your last command with `REGEXP='{W}'` to find out that it matches the byte of `W`. There is no hope if the locale encoding of characters may include bytes that match characters in the C locale. UTF-8 is inmune to such problem, every byte is either ascii or "something else". In UTF-8 no byte value of a multibyte character will match an ASCII (0-127) byte.

Comment: @Arrow, is that not exactly what I said in that answer?

Comment: No, it is not. I am not using a range. Even using a single character (`W`) fails. Your fist regexp will also fail.

Comment: @Arrow, no, that's the point, `LC_ALL=C grep '^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$'` as a special case works because that matches on lines that consist solely of characters of the portable character set that are guaranteed to be encoded the same in all the charsets of all the locales on a given POSIX system. In the general case (including in `grep '[A-Z]'` or `grep W` which match on my BIG5-HKSCS `Á`) that is not OK.